# How to check the last element of a python list?

Tags: python, list, stack

In python I need a stack, and I'm using a *list* for it. In the documenation it says that you can use *append()* and *pop()* for stack operations but what about accessing the top of the stack without removing it?

How to do that in the most readable way? Because all I came up with is `stack[-1:][0]` which looks a bit ugly for me, there must be a better way.

Comment: What documentation?  Can you provide the link or an example?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No need to slice.

```
stack[-1]
```

Comment: AAh, so that's why I got a second list because the colon makes slices.

Answer (score 2):

`stack[-1]` ist the last element

**EDIT** renamed the previously `list` called variable (Thanks, Tim McNamara).

Comment: Naming a variable `list` is a bad idea

Comment: you're right, this was for demonstration, but a bad idea anyways.